# Drools: Prioritize fact matching based on a field's value

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

Consider the following scenario in Drools:
We have a rule, matching objects of type `A` and `B` against each other.

```
rule 1
    when
        $a : A()
        $b : B($a.matches($b), flagged == false)
    then
        mofidy($b) { flag($a) }
end
```

However, `A` objects have a field called `priority`, and when a `B` arrives in the working memory, a matching `A` with the highest priority should flag it, above all other matching `A`s.
How is this possible in Drools? How does it affect performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `B.flag()` is setting its `flagged` attribute to true, you can try something like this:

```
rule 1
when
    $a : A()
    not A(this != $a, priority > $a.priority)
    $b : B($a.matches($b), flagged == false)
then
    mofidy($b) { flag($a) }
end
```

One thing to notice in this example is that if an A object with a high priority is inserted, any B that was already flagged with a lower A will not be reflagged.

If you need to reflag yours Bs, then you can try something like this:

```
rule 1
when
    $a : A()
    not A(this != $a, priority > $a.priority)
    $b : B($a.matches($b), flag != $a)
then
    mofidy($b) { flag($a) }
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does the `when` segment choose the `A` with the highest priority and then check if it matches any `B`? Or does it choose the highest matching `A` for the given `B`?

Comment: The first condition is checking for any `A` and the second is filtering the `A` with highest priority (it is actually filtering all of them except for the one with highest priority).